# Text overflow entire strings if part of the string is hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Given both these emails "Example@example.com" and "Blahblahblahblah@example.com". While displaying them both in a table if both emails can't be displayed fully then they are clipped in their entirety. So "Example@example.com, Blahblahblahblah@ex..." is supposed to be cut down to "Example@example.com, ..."

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow):

```css
div{
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, I mean if adipiscing has any overflow, then the string becomes "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..."

Comment: @Korsaurus It shows "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi..." for me.

Comment: Maybe this'll be a bit more clear: Given both these emails "Example@example.com" and "Blahblahblahblah@example.com". While displaying them both in a table if both emails can't be displayed fully then they are clipped in their entirety. So "Example@example.com, Blahblahblahblah@ex..." is supposed to be cut down to "Example@example.com, ..."